# Impersonating sqlcmd.exe from Local service : Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'

Tags: sql-server, powershell, impersonation

I'm running an impersonated sqlcmd.exe from a local service running under local system account.

I wrote a small utility to run process as user in order to correctly perform impersonation from this service.
So impersonation is performed correctly from this service, when I run `whoami.exe /all` with my target impersonation account, it reports the correct account information.

Nevertheless, when I run sqlcmd.exe with the same target impersonation account, It fails with the following output:

```
Running "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\sqlcmd.exe -b -E -S mydbserver.mydomain.net -Q "my sql command"" (working directory: "C:\")
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'..
```

I known the sqlcmd as been correctly impersonated, but I do not understand why the connection is performed with this account instead of impersonated account.

The machines setup is as follow:

- mydbserver.mydomain.net : running a SQL Server 12.0.2000 instance
- mybuildserver.mydomain.net : running a powershell script under a local system service account where it impersonate sqlcmd.exe (Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0)

The impersonation is performed using the win API CreateProcessAsUser function.

Comment: What is RunProcessAsUser? Do you mean CreateProcessAsUser?

Comment: @Ben, yes it's indeed CreateProcessAsUser, I edited my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you have a token for the user which is valid on the local machine only. Although you can impersonate the user on that machine you cannot delegate the impersonation to another machine.

In order to delegate the impersonation to another machine you must either:

- Have an impersonation token for a login which was created as `NetworkCleartext` or `Interactive`
- Have access to the user's password
- Have an impersonation token for a Kerberos (Active Directory) login AND your process must be "trusted for impersonation".

This is for security reasons: In order to impersonate a user on the local machine you only need to be an administrator on the local machine. If you could delegate impersonation to another machine without knowing the password, this would allow any local administrator on any machine to impersonate any user on the network on any machine. They could then grant themselves domain admin permissions and rule the network. Clearly this cannot be allowed.

Comment: I was obtaining a token from LogonUser with the "Network" logon type. Testing with "NetworkClearText" fixed the problem. Nevertheless, I'm concerned about security issue that could be raised from this. Could you please explain how I could use this token while making my process "trusted for impersonation" ?

Comment: It sounds like you have access to the user's password. Is that right? (As opposed to using `ImpersonateNamedPipeClient` or whatever)

Comment: you are correct, I have the user credential. I do not know about `ImpersonateNamedPipeClient`

Comment: Well no problem then. Just use `LogonUser` with `NetworkCleartext`. (Note that if you are using IIS you can also configure the application to impersonate automatically for you, which would be the recommended method as it can also handle Kerberos and so on.) The only reason to use anything else is if you don't have the password or want to rearchitect your solution to not require the password (e.g. in a Kerberos single-sign-on scenario).

Answer (score 1):

This is "two hops" (one hop from your client to the service process, the second hop from the process to the SQL server). Two hops require you to properly configure constrained delegation. See [How to: Configure an Application to Use Constrained Delegation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa528759.aspx). If you're lucky then you run a Windows Server 2012 domain and you have a much simplified procedure, see [What's New in Kerberos Authentication](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh831747.aspx) and [How Windows Server 2012 Eases the Pain of Kerberos Constrained Delegation](http://windowsitpro.com/security/how-windows-server-2012-eases-pain-kerberos-constrained-delegation-part-1). If you're stuck with a pre-2012 domain then unfortunately you'll be stuck with the painful old way:

- On the domain controller, clear the **Account is sensitive and cannot be delegated** check box for the account under which the client application is running.
- On the domain controller, select the **Account is trusted for delegation** check box for the account under which the client application is running.
- On the domain controller, configure the middle tier computer so that it is trusted for delegation, by clicking the **Trust computer for delegation option**.
- On the domain controller, configure the middle tier computer to use constrained delegation, by clicking the **Trust this computer for delegation to specified services only** option. You must specify the target SQL Server instance SPNs.